# How to design a db on firestore or firebase realtime db for a rotating shift

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure how to model a DB on firebase for a rotating shift. There's a 12 hour day and night shift and it rotates every 2 weeks.

My current hackish solution is to just use json and define every single day in a year with who's working day and night shift, like below. But it's obviously not optimal as I would have to define it every year, and I want it to be easy to add on other employee/shift details later.

```
year{
    month{
        day{
            1{empX:night,
              empY:morning;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked into other answers and a few videos and search results but I couldn't find what I'm looking for. I'm also open to using mysql instead but I want to try using firebase because of the one-stop console.

Hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the employees don't change during the 2 weeks (meaning you don't need per-day customization, just per-2-week customization), would something like this work? I don't know enough about your needs, but this came to mind:

```
shifts (collection)
  shiftId (Firebase generated doc id)
    start (timestamp)
    end (timestamp, 2 weeks later)
    dayShift (array)
      employeeId (string)
      employeeId (string)
      employeeId (string)
    nightShift (array)
      employeeId (string)
      employeeId (string)
      employeeId (string)
```